# Are coroutines worth using with type mapping?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-jetpack, kotlin-coroutines

Is it worth calling the coroutines in order to perform type mapping operations? Or it's going to be too much code bloating and/or overhead?

So the scenario is the following:

- Repo returns objects of `LiveData<List<A>>`
- View needs objects of type `LiveData<<List<GUI_A>>`
- `ViewModel` exposes `LiveData<GUI_A>` by using `Transformations.map` and the source `LiveData<A>` coming from the repo.

The `Transformations.map` code looks something like this

```
fun doSomethingWithRepoData(repoData: LiveData<List<A>>): LiveData<List<GUI_A>> =
    Transformations.map(repoData) { 
        it.map { GUI_A.fromRepoObject(it) }
    }
```

The function `fromRepoObject` only maps properties from the first object to the new instance of the second one.

The idea is to use coroutines in the map function to improve performance; but I don't know if it is going to be worth the hassle:

```
fun doSomethingWithRepoData(repoData: LiveData<List<A>>): LiveData<List<GUI_A>> =
    Transformations.map(repoData) { 
        it.map { async { GUI_A.fromRepoObject(it) } }
          .map { it.await() }
    }
```

Comment: It depends if you need the data to continue, you'll still need to wait for the thread to finish its task, or if you can do something while the work is being done?

Comment: The main focus is to keep the UI thread as free as possible. I know that Transformations.map run on the UI thread. So I would rather have a worker thread do the mapping for me. But I'm not sure if this approach has an actual impact or I'm just bloating my code

Comment: Since the computation is not tIme consuming , I would not recommend to use coroutine for this simple computation.

Comment: what if there are, like 1.000.000 elements? Like particles in a videogame or something

Comment: since its purely based on your use case , if computation is complex then its good to use coroutines

Comment: It's primarily filtering a subset of variables. They are assignations and mappings of sublists

Comment: If you have many items to map using a bit of computation, as opposed to a few items with heavy computation on each one, your scheme will degrade performance due to the overhead of context switching. You have to batch items together in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definitive answer, and I hate it, is that **it depends**.

Switching thread's context doesn't come for free and it has some accumulated overhead on doing so you have to watch out for data's magnitude before considering one thing or another.

- Mapping 15 elements? Probably not worth it.
- Mapping 1000? Maybe! do they have nested lists and maps that should also be mapped?
- Mapping 1_000_000? Definitely!

We should also watch out for our mapping implementations.

The given example:

```
fun doSomethingWithRepoData(repoData: LiveData<List<A>>): LiveData<List<GUI_A>> =
    Transformations.map(repoData) { 
        it.map { async { GUI_A.fromRepoObject(it) } }
          .map { it.await() }
    }
```

It's a **don't** do.

You see; `LiveData` assures that the code observing the `LiveData` is running on the main thread. On one hand that's good because it assures main safety but on the other hand it's "bad" in this case because the main thread waits for all of the corutines to finish their mapping operations before pushing a value.

A smarter approach to this, assuming we're in a `ViewModel` may be:

```
class SampleVM: ViewModel(){

    fun doSomethingWithRepoData(repoData: LiveData<List<A>>): LiveData<List<GUI_A>> = 
    Transformations.switchMap(repoData) { listA ->
        val result = MutableLiveData<List<GUI_A>>()
        // Don't block the UI thread by running in a coroutine
        viewModelScope.launch {
            listA
                 // Parallelize computation
                 .map { async(Dispatchers.Default) { GUI_A.fromRepoObject(it) }
                 // The viewModelScope job will await for all coroutines to finish mapping
                 .map { it.await() }
                 // Post the result to into the live data
                 .let { result.postValue(it) }
        }

        result
    }


}
```